# Distributing 1 satoshi to every user on stack exchange or some other online community

Tags: wealth-distribution, airdrop

I'm curious if there have been any coins that has distributed coins to an entire online community like an air drop. Currently many online communities like stack exchange have public profiles and public User IDs. If someone was to catalog every one of these users and generate a bitcoin address for them, then sent them 1 satoshi on the lightning network, it would be an interesting distribution model.

- Has any coin done something like this?

Comment: That would be interesting, for all of SE to be able to claim one satoshi by a private key generated from their user ID. Also, not very secure.

Comment: @Willtech One could potentially have a chat bot handle it, and require users to join a chatroom and provide the bot with an address. That's pretty much asking for a bad actor to try and log into all the SO accounts with password dumps, though.

Comment: I can't see any other way to do this without it being centralized for the initial phase. As sending 1 satoshi out to 100,000 addresses. The fees would be kinda crazy.

Answer (score 3):

A few projects have done this (although more recently with EOS and Ethereum). The only notable one I can remember off the top of my head is [Clamcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=623147.0):

> Every person who had Bitcoin at block 300,377, Litecoin at block 565,693, or Dogecoin at block 218,556 was given ~4.6 CLAM.

This has spawned a few digging services over the years, where you can upload old LTC, BTC, or Doge wallets (after removing those coins, of course) and get Clamcoin out.

On Ethereum, [`0x31a240648e2baf4f9f17225987f6f53fceb1699a`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x31a240648e2baf4f9f17225987f6f53fceb1699a#internaltx) distributed `0.000000007777777777 ETH` to some `174,655` addresses as a marketing gimmick for an ICO called Safe. Many other Ethereum ICOs conduct air drops, usually with some rules like "Any address that sent or received ETH between X and Y blocks".

More recently, some EOS projects have been "spamming" [free `0.0001 EOS`](https://old.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/92bk3y/is_spam_advertising_through_00001_eos_transfers/) to various accounts

I do believe that Clamcoin is the only major example of distribution based on community participation at that scale, though.